# app was working then began crashing on startup. Cannot figure out why

Tags: crash, startup

Here is the LogCat

```
08-09 03:38:15.288: E/cutils-trace(927): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-09 03:38:17.738: E/cutils-trace(938): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dip.allnavyinfo/com.dip.allnavyinfo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class Textview
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class Textview
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at com.dip.allnavyinfo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  ... 11 more
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.Textview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dip.allnavyinfo-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.dip.allnavyinfo-1, /system/lib]]
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
08-09 03:38:21.968: E/AndroidRuntime(949):  ... 21 more
```

Comment: Looks like you're using Android Studio - anyway, check the xmls for errors.

Comment: Error free. Debugged everything. Using Eclipse

Comment: Paste the xml, you're probably using some scroll attribute or something else, which is problematic for some devices.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with my text view at line 13. I took the text view out and it works perfectly.